# Sorting Arrays method not working

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I guess my main method has an issue in it, but i'm not really sure. Hope anyone could help.

```
    package testing;
    import java.util.*;

    public class mid08 {
       public static int[] Sort(int[]x) {
       int max=max(x);
       int[] y=new int[max+2];
       for(int i=0;i<x.length;i++)
         y[x[i]+1]++;
         return y;
    }
    public static int max(int[] x){
     int max=x[0];
     for(int i=0;i<x.length;i++){
      if(x[i]>max)
       max=x[i];
    }
    return max;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] z = new int[] {2,3,5,1};
        Sort(z);
        System.out.print(Arrays.toString(z));
    }
    }
```

I'm sure of both my methods but not of the main method itself.

Comment: Why do you think your main method has a problem?

Comment: What's it doing? Any error messages? Does it hang? Are you getting output other than what you expected?

Comment: General advice:  Your code is very difficult to read; you should learn the standard Java naming and indentation rules, and follow them.

Answer (score 1):

You ignore the result of your sort:

```
z = Sort(z);
System.out.print(Arrays.toString(z));
```

Should fix your issue.

Comment: omg thanks a bunch m8, didn't see that the first time.